# Regex: Match everything but one word

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression pattern, that matches everything but one exact word.

For example, resolutions:

```
monitors/resolutions // Should not match
monitors/34          // Should match
monitors/foobar      // Should match
```

I know that you can exclude a list of single characters, but how do you exclude a complete word?

Comment: This is one of the most frequently asked questions here, please search before asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negative lookahead assertion,

```
^(?!.*resolutions).*$
```

OR

```
^(?!.*\bresolutions\b).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qR8uN5/3)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(str){
    let match,
        arr = [],
        myRe = /monitors\/((?:(?!resolutions)[\s\S])+)/g;

    while ((match = myRe.exec(str)) != null) {
         arr.push(match[1]);
    } 

  return arr;
}

console.log(test('monitors/resolutions'));
console.log(test('monitors/34'));
console.log(test('monitors/foobar'));
```

```js
function test(str){
    let match,
        arr = [],
        myRe = /monitors\/(\b(?!resolutions\b).+)/g;

    while ((match = myRe.exec(str)) != null) {
         arr.push(match[1]);
    } 

  return arr;
}

console.log(test('monitors/resolutions'));
console.log(test('monitors/34'));
console.log(test('monitors/foobar'));
```